# Cannot save a OneToOneField for a User

Tags: django

I have a User object that has an additional attribute defined by UserExtra model:

```
class UserExtra(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_extra')
    favourite_cake = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

My user:

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> u
<User: rabid_sparrow>
```

I would like to add a `favourite_cake` attribute to this user. I tried doing this:

```
>>> u.user_extra.favourite_cake = 'black forrest'
>>> u.save()
>>> u.user_extra.favourite_cake 
u'black forrest'
```

However, if I immediately reload the user, the attribute is not set:

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> u.user_extra.favourite_cake
>>> 
>>> type(u.user_extra.favourite_cake)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

I tried to manually save the field, but this raised a user_id is not unique error:

```
>>> ue = UserExtra(user=u, favourite_cake='black forrest')
>>> ue.save()
-snip-
IntegrityError: column user_id is not unique
```

What is the correct way to save `favourite_cake` for User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don`t know what is wrong with last example, but in first you need to save user_extra:

```
>>> u.user_extra.favourite_cake = 'black forrest'
>>> u.user_extra.save()
```

and then try to reload user.